# SharePoint 2013 Workflow, log shipping supported?

Tags: 2013, workflow, disaster-recovery

We plan on implementing log shipping for SharePoint DR environment.

I found details about SharePoint databases and Log shipping support here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj841106.aspx

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the same for Workflow databases:
SpGatewayDatabase,
SbManagementDB,
SbMessageContainer01,
WFInstanceManagementDB,
WFManagementDB,
WFResourceManagementDB

On this page, it is said that log-shipping is a possible choice:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730570(v=azure.10).aspx

but it doesn't say if all DBs can be log shipped.
Does someone know which databases support log shipping ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for Workflow Manager Disaster Recovery? do we need to enable log-shipping for all the workflow manager databases SpGatewayDatabase, SbManagementDB, SbMessageContainer01, WFInstanceManagementDB, WFManagementDB, WFResourceManagementDB ?

Comment: Hi Ram, I am currently in contact with MS on this case. We had to contact the support because nobody could answer at the partner community support. I already have a beginning of answer, I'll  post the results here during the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from MS.

The databases which support log shipping are the following :

- SbGatewayDatabase
- SbMessageContainer01
- WFInstanceManagementDB
- WFResourceManagementDB

Those who don't :

- SbManagementDB
- WFManagementDB

I was wondering if other SbMessageContainerXX DB would appear automatically, but it won't. You can add new SBMessageContainer DB manually, in that case you should include them in your recovery process.

Comment: So does this mean, since SbManagementDB & WFManagementDB don't support log shipping, we should set their DB Recovery Model to Simple?

Comment: if you switch to your disaster recovery environment you don't need to recover those 2 databases. You will have to execute configuration wizard of workflow manager which will recreate those databases. Then you will attach the 4 other db to your new farm by a bunch of commands that you can find here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730570%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  see section "Disaster recovery process"

Comment: It is a long and difficult recovery process, MS didn't published all the required commands on Msdn. I would recommand another DR option if available.

Comment: http://sprecipe.com/2016/01/12/a-few-words-about-workflow-manager-disaster-recovery-and-log-shipping/

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served to configure the DR farm with same workflow manager, not log ship it, and just log ship your content db's